# Удалить jade из проекта

Tags: jade

В проекте установлен `"gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",`. Как его удалить через консоль cmd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[npm uninstall gulp-jade](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall)

Если вы хотите удалить его не просто с диска, но и из зависимостей, то нужно добавить флаг *--save*, *--save-dev* или *--save-optional*, в зависимости от того, в какой секции указана зависимость.

Comment: сделала так `npm uninstall gulp-jade -save/--save-dev/--save-optional`. но в файле package.json по прежнему видно что он установлен. в консоли это так https://i.gyazo.com/fa8c812527b24e389a94375bb24a3897.png

Comment: разобралась, спасибо)